# Choose Image from Gallery/Camera and display in a ListView

Tags: android, image, listview

I want to set Images chosen from either gallery or camera into a ListView. The selected images are stored in sqlite db.

The following is my OnActivityResult class:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case CAMERA_REQUEST:

                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                    if (extras != null) {
                        Bitmap yourImage = extras.getParcelable("data");
                        // convert bitmap to byte
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
                        Log.e("outputbeforeconversion", imageInByte.toString());
                        // Inserting Contacts
                        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                        db.addContact(new Contact("Android", imageInByte));
                        Intent i = new Intent(ForSaleAndRentUpload.this,
                                ForSaleAndRentUpload.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();

                    }
                    break;
                case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
                    Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();

                    if (extras2 != null) {
                        Bitmap yourImage = extras2.getParcelable("data");
                        // convert bitmap to byte
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
                        Log.e("outputbeforeconversion", imageInByte.toString());
                        // Inserting Contacts
                        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                        db.addContact(new Contact("Android", imageInByte));
                        Intent i = new Intent(ForSaleAndRentUpload.this,
                                ForSaleAndRentUpload.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have this dialogbox the help me choose either to select from gallery or from camera directly. When I choose to select image from any of the option, I go to the same activity but the ListView is empty.

Adapter:

```
public class ContactImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    // BcardImage data[] = null;
    ArrayList<Contact> data=new ArrayList<Contact>();
    public ContactImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Contact> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ImageHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ImageHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textInvi);
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.listImageItem);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Contact picture = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(picture._name);
        //convert byte to bitmap take from contact class

        byte[] outImage=picture._image;
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
        Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(theImage);
        return row;

    }

    static class ImageHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }




}
```

DB that stores the images:

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "imagedb";
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";


    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void addContact(Contact contact){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact._name); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, contact._image); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }

    Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_IMAGE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getBlob(2));

        // return contact
        return contact;

    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM contacts ORDER BY name";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setImage(cursor.getBlob(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // close inserting data from database
        db.close();
        // return contact list
        return contactList;

    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, contact.getImage());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });

    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }

    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
```

Log, when the image is selected:

```
03-11 07:00:45.622    1773-1773/com.iwillcode.realestate E/Selected Item﹕ 1
03-11 07:00:46.507    1773-1773/com.iwillcode.realestate W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-11 07:00:47.476    1773-1796/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-11 07:00:47.477    1773-1796/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3a76c00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-11 07:00:51.252    1773-1796/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-11 07:00:51.252    1773-1796/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa373b080, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-11 07:00:52.710    1773-1773/com.iwillcode.realestate E/Selected Item﹕ 1
03-11 07:00:53.667    1773-1773/com.iwillcode.realestate W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-11 07:00:54.456    1773-1796/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-11 07:00:54.456    1773-1796/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa3a76c00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: `set Images chosen from either gallery or camera into a ListView. `. Please tell from where the user starts to select an image. Where should the image be placed? (In the listview is too vague). If you don't have troubles putting the image in the database then why are you posting code for it?

Comment: Please comment on your log.

Comment: But where do you need help? You did not tell what goes wrong. You did not tell what goes ok. What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Working code (Main Activity)

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CameraActivity = this;

        imageView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        database = new ImageDatabase(this);

        //Set OnClick Listener to button view
        captureImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_image);
        captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                isStoragePermissionGranted();
            }
        });

        //long press on image
        imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                isStoragePermissionGranted();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void startDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                CameraActivity);
        myAlertDialog.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
        myAlertDialog.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");

        myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setType("image/*");
                        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(i.createChooser(i, "Result load Image")
                                , GALLERY_IMAGE);
                    }
                });

        myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    }
                });
        myAlertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        //Code for @CAMERA_REQUEST
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        }

        //Code for @GALLERY_IMAGE
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            theImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ImageDatabase.KEY_IMG_URL, byteArray);
            db.insert(ImageDatabase.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            //db.update(ImageDatabase.TABLE_NAME, values, null, null);
            db.close();

    }

    public void getTheImage() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + ImageDatabase.TABLE_NAME,
                null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] imgByte = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageDatabase.KEY_IMG_URL));
            //cursor.close();
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);

        }
        //if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
         //   cursor.close();
        //}
        mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this,cursor);
        imageView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);
    }

    //Storage permission
    public boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
                startDialog();
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v(TAG, "Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                        {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(TAG, "Permission is granted");
            startDialog();
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getTheImage();
    }
}
```

Image adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public ImageAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Inflate a list item view using the layout specified in list_item.xml
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Find individual views that we want to modify in the list item layout
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

        byte[] imgByte = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageDatabase.KEY_IMG_URL));
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
}
```

Database class

public class ImageDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public Context context;

```
//Database name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "imageData";

//Version
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//SQL Table detail;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "DATA";
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_IMG_URL = "imagedisplayed";

public ImageDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Constructor called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID +
        " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_IMG_URL + " BLOB " + ")";
public static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void deleteEntry(long row) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + "=" + row, null);
}
```

}

Don't Forget to mention User permission code in Manifest.